# IOS: problem with certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I used a mac at work where I created .ipa without problems and I tried my app on device.
Now at home (in another mac) when I choose device on my project and I do "build" I have an error:

Code Signing Identity 'iPhone Developer
does not match any valid, non-expired, code-signing certificate in your keychain

why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. You need to export your certificates and profiles from your mac at work, and import them at home. It is really annoying, you can just download the certificates and profiles to one mac, it wont work if you download then again onto another mac, after having them already used on another machine. If you are having issues exporting and importing profiles, then you can google for some tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

On your mac at work, you've added the code-signing certificate to your keychain.  You need to do the same for your mac at home.  You can download the certificate from the developer portal, same as you did for your work computer.

Comment: Double-click on it to add it to your keychain. Presumably, since you've already deployed to this device before, the project already has the correct code-signing identity configured and the device already has a provisioning profile.  All the steps are described [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW1)

Comment: Ok i do double click on it and it appeared on keychain, but I have ever the same problem

Comment: Have you [selected this identity](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/120-Building_and_Running_Applications/building_and_running_applications.html) in your Project setup?